# Does anyone know how to zoom in on NetBeans code?

Tags: netbeans

I want to enlarge the code I've written in NetBeans so it's easier to read.  I can enlarge the output by using ctrl and '+', but it doesn't work on the code.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Alt+Scroll Wheel (on mouse) will do it.  If you want to change the font size, go to Tools>Options>Fonts&Colors [note: this is a large icon/tab].  From there, in the Syntax tab (default) click Default, then the '...' button next to Font.  Change the font size here, and click Okay.  Other fonts inherit this size, so that should be the only change.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a Fonts&Colors under Tools on my NetBeans @aring

Comment: Which version of NetBeans are you using?

Comment: Tools/Options is most likely meant here.. the dialog then contains the "fonts&colors" panel. On mac the dialog is under Netbeans/Preferences

Comment: I'm using version 7.3.1 @aring, and it was Tools>Options>Fonts&Colors.  I was a bit fatigued last night.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, you're right, sorry I accidentally left out the Options in the path!  Corrected now.

Comment: Till now every time i accidentally zoom in or zoom out I restarted the Netbeans IDE because i didn't know what i clicked. Alt + Scroll also works on Netbeans 8.0.

Comment: (see also)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081513/how-to-zoom-text-in-netbeans-without-mousewheel]

Answer (score 12):

press { <kbd>ALT</kbd> (your keyboard) + <kbd>Scroll wheel</kbd> (your mouse) };

Answer (score 6):

NetBeans 7.2 changes the behaviour slightly – now you need to initiate a press down click on the scroll wheel whilst scrolling to increase/decrease the font size. No keyboard assistance required!
- ref  http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2012/10/16/how-to-quickly-increase-or-descrease-the-font-size-in-netbeans-ide/

Comment: Does anyone kown how to get back to Standard Zoom Level? I alway accidentaly scroll and zoom inside the code.

Comment: @kasoft Maybe a little workaround, but it works: note the number of lines of code visible in editor tab with "no zoom" and then scroll up/down in tab where You have accidentally change zoom level to match the number of lines. On my 24" screen I can see about 120 lines of code with notifications/output/terminal tab opened below editor.

Answer (score 4):

Just press "alt" and scrool and normally it's oke

Comment: This solution was already given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50808646/9199167) by [PichetNart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3538450/pichetnart). Please check existing answers and upvote those you find helpful, instead of adding duplicates. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> If you want to zoom In/Out the code file /source window use this below method.

press  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  key`+ scroll Mouse wheel up for Zoom In and scroll Mouse wheel down for Zoom Out`

> If you want to zoom In/Out the output window/terminal use this below method.

press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  key`+ scroll Mouse wheel up for Zoom In and scroll Mouse wheel down for Zoom Out`

Answer (score 1):

Visit [here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/53555/editor-zoom) and download the zooming plugin.

Steps to Install Plugin:

1. Open Tools
2. Select Plugin
3. Goto Available Plugins Tab
4. Search for Zoom and install the plugin
5. Restart NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

Lots of "mouse driven" answers here. But not everyone uses a mouse anymore. To Zoom In/Out of the Output Window of Netbeans 11.x do this, it's simple.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while pressing the <kbd>Arrow Up</kbd> (to zoom in) and <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd> (to zoom in) keys on your keyboard.

Comment: This works only in the output window. Not in a source file window.