# How to zoom text in netbeans without mousewheel?

Tags: netbeans

If your mouse is all right, you can easily [alter the font size in netbeans using mousewhee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18553906/607407)l. Unfortunatelly, my mousewheel is broken and returns random values when scrolled.
I just happened to accidentally zoom text out with that broken wheel. I want back the default zoom - but doing this using the mouse might take eternity. I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> (as in browsers) but that didn't work.

Can this be done? Can it be done easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Tools|Options|Keymap and look for "Zoom text in" and "Zoom text out". You can assign it any shortcut you want