# How to reset text zoom in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-10

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553853/does-anyone-know-how-to-zoom-in-on-netbeans-code/18553906) and its answer explain how to zoom in and out on text in NetBeans, namely <kbd>Alt</kbd> + mouse wheel. But after you have zoomed in or out with the mouse wheel, **how do you reset the zoom to the default setting?** Restarting NetBeans resets it, but that's kind of inconvenient.

I happen to be using NetBeans 10.0.